# Removing a sort from dataview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, dataview

I have a dataview which binds to a PagedDataSource object. The data is pulled into the dataview from the db using a stored procedure and the returned data is sorted according to a date field. The stored proc is used in several places in the application and so I cant make any big change in this instance. I just need to disable the sort order which is returned by the stored proc (Without making any change to the stored proc) and apply a new sort.

```
 objPagedDs = New PagedDataSource()
 dvFeedback = objCompany.PublishedMonitoringCards.DefaultView
 dvFeedback.RowFilter = "EligibleForPrinting = 1"
 dvFeedback.Sort = "IncludeInRepReport DESC, Work_dt DESC"
```

Please find the code above.

Comment: Ok, what is the question ? What issue are you facing ?

Comment: I have said in the question " I just need to disable the sort order which is returned by the stored proc (Without making any change to the stored proc) and apply a new sort."

Comment: @KPL has a valid point. You state you need to "disable" the sort, and your code shows that you have done exactly that. So, what **is** the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 0,1,and null values in the database. It sorts Includeinreport in descending order. That means it sorts in the order of 1,0, and null. Apparently I want the null to be 0 when it returns from the database to make the sort working the way I want. Used ISNULL to do it. Doesnt relate to question but this what I did. The above code snippet is fine.